# Form-data req.body showing up as undefined buffer is fine

Tags: node.js, express, multer

My server can parse JSON but do i need some additional parser to make sense of form-data req.body? I can read the req.file.buffer fine. Also using multer middleware.

```
const express = require('express')
const Controllers = require('./Controllers');
const app = express();
const port = 3001;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist');
app.use('/', express.static(DIST_DIR));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));

app.post('/links', upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  const imageName = req.file.filename;
  const description = req.body;
  const buffer = req.file.buffer.toString('base64');
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send();
});
```

Comment: you'll need to show the code which makes the request, as server code seems fine